# Deploy fabric script to multiple users of a same machine

Tags: python, bash, fabric

Is it possible (and how) to run a fab script for multiple users on a same machine. For example, say I have users `user1` and `user2` on a remote machine and I want to use a fabfile that runs a bash script that uses the `$HOME` environment variable. I need to run the bash script twice, first as `user1` and then as `user2`.

Comment: Have you tried using `su -c`? Exmaple being `su -c "/some/directory/Script" user1`

Comment: You could then throw it into a `for` loop for as many users as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You could run multiple commands and add as many users as you need.

```
for i in user1 user2 user3 ; do
  su -c "/some/directory/Script" ${i}
done
```

Comment: You could also use `sudo -u ${i} "/some/directory/Script"` I believe.

Comment: Good suggestion, I did not have thought of it ! I'll try tomorrow, thanks !